# How to check if move constructor is autogenerated?

Tags: c++, c++11, move, move-semantics

Is move contructor autogenerated ???

cppreference documentation

Types without a move constructor, but with a copy constructor that accepts const T& arguments, satisfy std::is_move_constructible

```
class X{
public:
     ~X()=default;

};
```

So i want to know if std::is_move_constructible::value is true because X genuinely has a default move constructor, not because it has a default a copy constructor?

Comment: Your question title isn't consistent with your question description. Whether the move constructor of `X` is "autogenerated" (which, to me, means "defaulted") is a different question from whether moving `X` falls back on the copy constructor.

Comment: If i implement the destructor move constructor is still available?

Comment: What about std::is_trivially_move_constructible?

Comment: Read [Move constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor), particularly the sections on "Implicitly-declared move constructor", "Deleted implicitly-declared move constructor", and "Trivial move constructor".

Comment: You got downvoted for asking a textbook question, but, I found it relevant enough to counter that downvote. Read the link Remy shared and you'll probably delete the question yourself.